# installing node.js on OS X (mountain lion) with homebrew: Could not autodetect OpenSSL support

Tags: macos, node.js, openssl, homebrew

I need to install node 0.6 on OS X Mountain Lion.  homebrew seems the easiest route (building from source failed to link).  With the command:

```
brew install node
```

It's complaining with the following:

```
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : not found 
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : not found 
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : not found 
/private/tmp/node-x1II/node-v0.6.19/wscript:386: error: 

Could not autodetect OpenSSL support. 
Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. 
Use configure --without-ssl to disable this message.
```

However, openssl seems to be installed:

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

What magical bit needs to be in place for homebrew to see openssl?

Comment: Not related to the question about hemobrew; but why can't you use the pkg from nodejs.org? [Here is the lastest 0.6.x pkg](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.21/node-v0.6.21.pkg).

Comment: That does work, thank you.  I was hoping to keep everything to a single package manager.  But since it's a pkg, it's contained.

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked, I'm sorry I can't help you with the homebrew thing.

Comment: This might not be the most helpful, but 'brew install node' worked for me. It actually installed v0.8.14, though, not v0.6.